# How can I externally decrypt the information that IONIC encrypts?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, encryption

My information that I encrypt in my IONIC app works without problems, also I have no problems with the internal decryption of IONIC, the problem lies in how I can decrypt this information in another web page, app, etcetera, I used an online AES-256 cbc encryption and decryption page, but it gives me an error.

This is my example:

SecureKEY: 0db9ffba3bf4ef272fa71b46866f79a4

SecureIV: 9010dfd0eefc0be3

Data Encrypted: /7rbraeTgQXRaDfIEvDkAQ==

Data Decrypted Data: 30099206713

I would appreciate your help.

It is an application in Ionic v5.6, I use the same IONIC AES256 plugin, and I am programming for Android 9.0 system.

Comment: Any update on this? I want to do the same.

Comment: @hardiksa sorry but no

Comment: @hardiksa If you manage to solve it, you could give me a hand, I stopped that little project because I couldn't find anything. Please